# Why are these flow lines cut short?

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus

I want to plot some flow lines for a certain vector field, but *Mathematica* doesn't seem to plot the entire flow line, only a small piece of it.  How can I fix this?

```
VectorPlot[{Re[Sqrt[x + I y]], Im[Sqrt[x + I y]]}, 
{x, -1, 1}, 
{y, -1, 1}, 
VectorPoints -> Fine,  
StreamPoints -> Coarse, 
StreamStyle -> Red, 
StreamScale -> None]
```

[image]

#### Update:

I feel dumb for not realizing the discontinuity, but I'll mention that what I really want are flow lines of slope fields, not vector fields.  I didn't see how to do this in *Mathematica* "directly," and hence used VectorPlot. How can I plot the lines of a slope field?

Comment: It plots from -1 to 1 in each direction. What do you want it to do?

Comment: If you mean the discontinuity along the negative x-axis, it's because the vector field is discontinuous and changes direction.

Comment: Chris, please register an account now so you can edit and manage your posts.

Comment: Could you explain what a "slope field" is?  Is it the same as a covector field (a one-form)?  Or a section of the circle bundle associated with the tangent bundle?  Or a section of that bundle with opposite directions identified at each point?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "slope field"? Preferably without using bundles for the pedestrians among us.

Comment: @whuber: The last option you mentioned, so there's no notion of forwards/backwards direction, just of tangency.

Comment: @acl: At each point you associate a the slope of a curve; so basically a vector field where a vector and its negative are identified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify seed-points for streamlines directly using `StreamPoints`: only those stremlines will be plotted which pass through these points. Here I set up two point sets: one at $y = 1$ and another at $y = -1$. These share identical $x$ coordinates so they meet at the discontinuity at $y = 0$. One can control the streamline lenghts by the third argument to `StremPoints` (second argument controls the minimal distance between streamlines).

```
points = Join[{#, -1.} & /@ Range[-1, 1, .2], {#, 1.} & /@ Range[-1, 1, .2]];
VectorPlot[{Re[Sqrt[x + I y]], Im[Sqrt[x + I y]]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,
   1}, VectorPoints -> Fine, StreamPoints -> {points, Automatic, 2}, 
 StreamStyle -> Red, StreamScale -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a small `Manipulate` interface to get a grip on how the streampoints are positioned and how length and distance can be controlled. Here a circular layout is used for the streamline-points to be able to capture some missing lines (thanks [whuber](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/91/whuber)!).

```
Manipulate[
 points = Table[{Cos@t, Sin@t}*r, {t, 0., 2. \[Pi], d}];
 VectorPlot[{Re[Sqrt[x + I y]], Im[Sqrt[x + I y]]}, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}, VectorPoints -> Fine, 
  StreamPoints -> {points, Automatic, l}, StreamStyle -> Red, 
  StreamScale -> None, 
  Epilog -> {Green, PointSize@Large, Point@points}],
 {{d, \[Pi]/20., "point spacing"}, 0, 1, \[Pi]/40, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{l, 2, "stream length"}, 0, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 1, "radius"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 How would you cope with the streamlines for positive $x$--the ones that ought to converge at the origin but instead are terminated within a distance of about $0.1$ of it?

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

For a slope field $dy/dx = f(y,x)$, I suppose you have to make do with something like a vector field of the form `{1, f[x,y]}` or `Normalize@{1, f[x,y]}`.  We might as well normalize the vector, since magnitude doesn't matter in a slope field.  Ordinarily, the value of the slope field at a point indicates the tangent line to an integral curve without regard to a direction of motion. I don't think *Mathematica* can represent that (or at least not conveniently).  You have to use a vector.

In your case, it seems better to treat $x$ as a function of $y$ and for $dx/dy = g(x,y)$, use `Normalize@{g[x,y], 1}`, where `g[x,y]` is the quotient of the `x` and `y` components of your vector field:

```
VectorPlot[
 Evaluate@Normalize@{Re[Sqrt[x + I y]]/Im[Sqrt[x + I y]], 1},
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 VectorPoints -> Fine, StreamPoints -> Coarse, 
 StreamStyle -> Red, StreamScale -> None, 
 VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0]]
```

[image: Vector field plot]